# In Adobe Audition, is there a way to capture entire Multitrack session as an Image, like JPEG or PNG?

Tags: adobe-audition, export, session, image

I want to show the procedure and look of my edit and mixing to people and also to client.

Is there a way to capture / export session mixed tracks as image formats like JPG or PNG ? Any script or plugin?!

Comment: Are you talking about the waveform as an image? Or just like a screenshot of your workstation?

Comment: Sorry for delay, I'm looking for a way to show the clips, maybe waveforms needed or not, but as an option it could be cool! btw seems like there is no way to get any graphical format out of it!

Answer (score 1):

To only show what's on your screen you can for ex. press the print screen key. It copies to the clipboard your screen content. You can open that content as a new image in Photoshop, GIMP or other image editor. Delete the unwanted extras and insert auxiliary explanations as needed and save the result.

I am afraid there's no easy method to capture with a single click a big project which needs several screens to be shown in any useful accuracy. But Photoshop has image merging functionality which combines several images to a single image with no problems in the seams and possible overlapping areas. You must manually crop the screenshots to contain only the waveform area.